# Swift Generics Inheritance

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to create an utils to make http request.
I want to use it like this :

```
    var callback = Callback<LoginResultBean>(onSuccess: { (data) -> () in

        print("TRUE");
        }) { (error) -> () in
            print("FALSE");
    }
    var handler = ConnectionHandler<LoginResultBean>(url : "https://.....", callback : callback);
```

LoginBeanResult can be change by any other model I want to retrieve from the server.

But I doesn't compile cause of this error : 
`'ConnectionHandler' requires that 'LoginResultBean' inherit from 'BaseModel'`

But LoginBeanResult already inherit from BaseModel so I don't understand this error.

Here is the class code :

```
//BaseModel.swift
import ObjectMapper
import Foundation

class BaseModel : NSObject, Mappable
{

    required init?(_ map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map)
    {

    }
}
```

.

```
//LoginBeanResult.swift
import ObjectMapper
import Foundation

class LoginResultBean : BaseModel {
    var jeton : String?;
    var etat : String?;
    var muna : String?;
    var idabo : String?;
    var codePostal : String?;
    var ville : String?;

    override func mapping(map: Map) {
        super.mapping(map);

        self.jeton <- map["jeton"];
        self.etat <- map["etat"];
        self.muna <- map["muna"];
        self.idabo <- map["idabo"];
        self.codePostal <- map["codePostal"];
        self.ville <- map["ville"];
    }
}
```

.

```
//ConnectionHandler.swift
import ObjectMapper
import Foundation

class ConnectionHandler<T: BaseModel> {

    var url : String;
    var callback : Callback<T>;

    init(url : String, callback : Callback<T>)
    {
        self.url = url;
        self.callback = callback;
    }

    func sendRequest(params : BaseModel)
    {
        let jsonData = Mapper().toJSONString(params, prettyPrint:false)?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let postLength : String = String(jsonData!.length);

        let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest();
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession();

        request.URL = NSURL(string: url);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length");
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type");
        request.HTTPBody = jsonData;

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            let response = Mapper<Response<T>>().map(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding));
            let code = response?.entete?.code;
            let message = response?.entete?.message;
            if(code == 0)
            {
                self.callback.onSuccess(data: (response?.corp)!);
            }
            else
            {
                let error = NSError(domain: "ConnectionHandler", code: code!, userInfo: NSDictionary(object: message!, forKey: NSLocalizedDescriptionKey) as [NSObject : AnyObject]);
                self.callback.onFailure(error: error);
            }
        });

        task.resume();        
    }

}
```

.

```
//Callback.swift
import ObjectMapper
import Foundation

class Callback<T: BaseModel>
{
    let onSuccess: (data : T) -> ()
    let onFailure: (error : NSError) -> ()

    init(onSuccess: (data : T) -> (), onFailure: (error : NSError) -> ())
    {
        self.onFailure = onFailure
        self.onSuccess = onSuccess
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your `Callback` class

Comment: Those semi-colons are hurting my eyes ;)

Comment: @t4nhpt see my edit :)

Comment: @MikePollard I'm lost without them ;)

Comment: I have tested, your code can run fine, I don't get your error. Try to clean and rebuild

Comment: :( did you try under an application or a framework project ? Cause I already try to clean and rebuild and I always have this error... I trying to create a framework (not static library) I can reuse in every project I will create. I will try to move code on an application and test it ! Thanks for your feedback! I'll let you know

Comment: Ok some of my classes was not checked/include to my testUnit project... So the message error was wrong and confuse me ^^. Thanks for your help !